# TypeScript is seeing interface type but not deducing correctly

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript

TypeScript compiler can't decide which type to use: or I don't understand what I'm doing.
Am i doing something wrong with the type inference

```
// In File A
type Func = (() => void) | ((id: number) => void);

interface A {
  [key: string]: (fn) => Func
}

interface B<G> {
  [Property in keyof G]: Func;
}
 
/* Example */
const AObjects: A = { 
  addName: function addName(fn): Func {
    return () => fn();
  },

  deletePerson: function deletePerson(fn): Func {
    return (id) => fn(id);
  }
}

const bObjects = {} as B<A>
for (let key in AObjects) {
  bObjects[key] = AObjects[key](fn);
}
export { bObjects };




// In File B
// Inside a reactnative file with a component
// The buttons are using interface B functions
import { bObjects } from 'fileA';

const Component = () => {
  const {
    addName,  // Type Func
    deletePerson // Type Func
  } = bObjects;
  
  return (
    <>
      <Button onPress={addName} /> // gives TypeScript Error -> deduces the types as ((id) => void) instead of (() => void)
      <Button onPress={() => deletePerson(id)} /> // correctly deduces the type as ((id) => void)
    </>
  );
}
```

In FileB,
the addName function does not evaluate to type () => void, it is throwing errors and asking for an id. The deletePerson works just fine. I am misunderstanding something or doing something wrong

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wXKoDW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

The onPress expects a () => void type. In the second case, that is what you are doing, `() => deletePerson(id)` is a void function with no arguments executing another one. In the first example, you are just passing `addName` directly. As per your function declaration, `addName` takes an argument of type number. If you did

```
<Button onPress={() => addName(id)} />
```

Then it would work.